# What' s the ways to run a process inside my process, without create another process?

Tags: winapi, process

I have a application where is my, I have the control of the code and I want to run another application without generate another process in Windows. I want this process to run inside my application process. Why I want to do that? Because I have some tests to do Subclass in this process, and SetWindowLong function only works if is running at the same process.

I know the approach to inject a dll in the process, but without doing a injection, there's a way to do that?

Comment: [`SetWindowLong[Ptr]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898.aspx) can be used across process boundaries. If, however, you want to use it with any of the pointer-type arguments (e.g. `GWLP_WNDPROC`) you may wish to reconsider. This type of last-millennium-subclassing is [no longer advised](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773183.aspx). Since you are talking about *testing* you may wish to consider a different approach altogether: [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx).

Comment: @IInspectable About SetWindowLongPtr in doc: *Windows XP/2000:   The SetWindowLongPtr function fails if the window specified by the hWnd parameter does not belong to the same process as the calling thread.*

Ps: I have to subclass a application running on the WinXp.

Comment: @IInspectable When I said test is not about application tests, is about to test a feature in my application.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot execute a new process inside an existing process. If you avail yourself of the functionality of the other processes as a library, then you will need to create another process. In which case, if you really do need to subclass a window, then you will need to inject code into the process that owns the window.

Comment: I found this code that do the work, but is not working, it compile and run ok, but nothing happens: https://www.cyberguerrilla.org/blog/?p=17942 The victim app is not even called.

Comment: That would be malware. Are you writing malware?

Comment: No, is not a malware, but is a security application for industry sector.

Comment: Anyway, I said my piece in the answer. There is no supported mechanism to do this. Which makes any attempt to do so be malware.